# Boncode AJP13 - Generic Connector Communication Error

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, windows-authentication

### IIS is redirecting to Tomcat but SSL is not occurring, basically web page opens but AD user is not "captured" in the process.

Application triggers - "User not Informed" error which is a designed error when AD account is not registered in the system. In our tests users are registered so I can conclude windows authentication does not occurs correctly

I get browser error:

**Generic Connector Communication Error: 
Please check and adjust your setup:
Ensure that Tomcat is running on given host and port.
If this is a timeout error consider adjusting IIS timeout by changing executionTimeout attribute in web.config (see manual).
connection between Tomcat and IIS experienced error. Please check logat BonCodeAJP13.BonCodeAJP13ServerConnection.p_CreateConnection(BonCodeAJP13PacketCollection packetsToSend)
 at BonCodeIIS.BonCodeCallHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)**

Are there any extra settings should I run in IIS or some IIS logs I could check to confirm which AD user is actually accessing tomcat?

Important notes:

- IIS8 (Windows SErver 2012) / apache-tomcat-7.0.64 / jdk-7u79-windows-x64
- Tomcat service is impersonating (log on as) an AD service account which connects to a SQL 2012 database. Connection to the database occurs through Microsoft JDBC driver.
- Only IIS root has a web.config file, application itself does not.
- Anonymous + Windows Authentication (Kerberos) are enabled in IIS.

Please let me know of any other relevant information should I provide to help on this troubleshooting.

Thank you so much for all help! 
BR

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the problem and fix it.
It was a misconfiguration on Tomcat server.xml "Connector" settings, Added up tomcatauthentication-"false" and now it works flawless.

```
            <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" tomcatAuthentication="false"/>
```